# What kinds of questions should be asked in Substrate StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, questions

Having a Substrate StackExchange is awesome, but I still have the question about what kinds of questions should be asked here?

For example, a development related question about the use of Substrate definitely falls into the exchange. But what about the *use* of a substrate-based blockchain.

For example a question like:

> How can I get all the ongoing crowdloan contributions using an RPC client for a relay-chain?

Would it be welcomed or not?

It is Substrate related of course, but in some cases it is more related to a specific runtime of a specific blockchain (built on Substrate, but still).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Questions about Parachains, Polkadot, Kusama, and other blockchains built with Substrate should be welcomed here.

Even questions about specific Parachain teams like Acala, Moonbeam, Astar, etc... should be welcomed, as long as they are appropriately tagged.

The Substrate ecosystem is vast and diverse, and we should look to support all of it as much as possible within the StackExchange.

What is more important (in my opinion) is the **kind** of questions that are asked. As with all StackExchange sites, they must be well contained, specific, tangible questions which can be answered accurately by the community.

Quality questions will lead to a quality site.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer.

I'm a frontend developer and therefore my work primarily involves building things like dashboards based on Polkadot's JS libraries (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/api). Sometimes I'll run into issues such as packages not installing properly, type defs not correct, or not understanding some of the data structures returned by the API.

Would such issues be relevant to ask on Substrate's StackExchange?

Comment: Things related directly to the clarity and understanding of Polkadot JS libraries definitely belong here, however I would think that things related to installing packages, or using Bable for instance, may be better served on the StackOverflow JavaScript forum, since these problems usually are not related to the Polkadot specific libraries, but just general JavaScript problem solving.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to figure this out, particularly during the private beta period, is to ask questions that you think are on the edge of being suitable and see how they're received.