# Should we be encouraging parachain specific questions on this site?

Tags: discussion, questions

It seems reasonable that statemint and encointer common good parachains' questions should be on this site.

Should we be encouraging other parachain teams to ask questions and answers here? I know the full gamut of what parachains are attempting to achieve is very broad, but sometimes they may be encountering the same problems in different domains. Also this might foster more cross-parachain collaboration and help spark things that might otherwise not come to be.

The downside is that people might find questions that they're not interested in. So far everything has been pretty well tagged so if I did not care for statemint I could exclude that tag if there were a lot of questions on that topic.

Curious on other's thoughts?

Comment: Some of this is already touched on here too: [What kinds of questions should be asked in Substrate StackExchange?](https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-kinds-of-questions-should-be-asked-in-substrate-stackexchange)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think we should absolutely encourage parachain teams to have their communities ask their questions here too.

It is all about:

1. Tagging them appropriately.
2. Having representatives from that community present to answer those questions.

I suspect in the short term, we will need to ping the other parachain communities when there are questions here for them. In time, they will check themselves.

Comment: Agreed with this 100% - it should be inclusive.